# What is causing licorice swirls to drop from dispensers?

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I'm playing Candy Crush Saga on Facebook (but I guess the mobile versions features the same levels) and I'm currently stuck on [Level 293](http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Level_293)

The main difficulty from this level is in my opinion the licorice dispensers that will block most of the board, preventing you from clearing it.
So my question is: **What is the exact condition that will decide if the dispenser will open or remain closed?** Causing licorice or regular candies to appear at the top of the board.

I was thinking at first it was some kind of random sequence, but I'm not so sure about that after a few tries: because the amount of licorice over the board seems to be changing a lot from one attempt to another. So I guess there is something I do that have a direct influence on this.

I found this on the wiki:

> A Candy Cannon (also well known as a dispenser) is an element that releases licorice swirls or candy bombs to the board when the candies in its vicinity are removed. ([Source](http://candy-crush-saga.wikia.com/wiki/Dispenser))

But I don't really agree with this, even if I only remove candies at the bottom of the board (the dispensers being at the top), they keep dropping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this out recently again and I did notice that if you in fact destroy the `Licorice Swirls` by a regular candy match, intentionally, it will stop spawning Licorice Swirls for the rest of the turn.

It doesn't matter where you destroy them. As long as you make a candy match that will destroy them it will stop spawning.

The strategy to beating this level is just try to limit the Licorice Swirls. Make matches on top of them when the left side of the board is half full of them.

Comment: I've read somewhere else (don't remember the link) that the cause of licorice being removed was different from one level to another... Anyway I've managed to finish this level and from what I've seen, you're right about this level, so I consider this the correct answer ;) Especially the "**regular candy match, intentionally**" part I wasn't figuring out when testing. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Some levels spawn Licorice Swirls no matter what while most others should stop spawning provided there is a candy match to destroy it. I've finished all the regular levels and I'm at 115 in Dreamworld.